# How to get background colors with fullCalendar and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I have a site that is mostly Bootstrap, but fullCalendar is so awesome that I couldn't avoid using it.

Unfortunately, the Bootstrap UI seems to override the event background colors. I tried using the fullCalendar directive. I tried CSS and I even tried using jQuery to add CSS after loading. Nothing works and all events are always white. Has anyone else encountered this problem? How can I assign colored backgrounds to events?

**CSS**

```
.fc-event-vert .fc-event-bg {
    background:#def;
}
```

**jQuery Try**

```
$('.fc-event-vert .fc-event-bg').css('background','#def');
```

My entire config looks like this: (note the eventColor tag that is NOT working)

```
    $('#calendar_div').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek'
    },
    defaultDate: yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot: false,
    minTime: '08:00:00',
    maxTime: '20:00:00',
    slotDuration: '00:15:00', 
    defaultTimedEventDuration: '01:00:00',
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    select: function (start,end) {
        var sdate = start.format();
        var edate = end.format();
        var thisdate = sdate.substr(0,10);
        var stime = sdate.substr(11);
        var etime = edate.substr(11);
        $.colorbox({
            href: "/appointments/create/"+thisdate+"/"+stime+"/"+etime+"/"+thispatient,
            iframe: false,
            width: "600",
            height: "528px",
            scrolling: true,
            escKey: true,
            overlayClose: true,
            title: "",
            close: "X",
            onClosed: function() {
            }
        });
    },
    events: '/appointments/get_appts',
    eventColor: '#fde',
    eventDrop: function (event) {
        var id = event.id;
        var sdate = event.start.format();
        var edate = event.end.format();
        $.ajax({ url: '/appointments/updateappt/'+id+'/'+sdate+"/"+edate });
    },
    eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        var id = event.id;
        $.ajax({ url: '/appointments/getappt/'+id,
                success: function(mydata) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(mydata);
                    $.colorbox({
                        href: '/appointments/create/'+data.sdate+'/'+data.stime+'/'+data.etime+'/'+data.uid,
                        iframe: false,
                        width: "600",
                        height: "528px",
                        scrolling: true,
                        escKey: true,
                        overlayClose: true,
                        title: "",
                        close: "X",
                        onClosed: function() {
                        }
                    });
                }
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some trouble with styling fullCalendar events because there is some inline styling involved. The best way that I have found for changing the event color is to use the fullCalendar API options for doing so.

When you can set the color for the entire calendar or for specific events. I've found that when I have lots of conflicting styles because of external stylesheets (like twitter-bootstrap) that setting the color for specific events is the best way to solve it. FullCalendar will then use inline styling on each event to set the background color so that other stylesheets won't override it.

Here is the documentation:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventColor/

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventBackgroundColor/

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Comment: I updated my post to include my call to eventColor. It still does not work. I always get white boxes.

Comment: Update! The above code DOES set the border color. It just won't set the background color. eventBackgroundColor also does not work. Something is over-riding the color. Maybe transparency or z-index? Does bootstrap over-ride wither of these items for tables?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I was loading the print css for fulLCalendar also. It had #ffffff !important set for background color.

Comment: If the print CSS is loading for the web version, you should add `media="print"` to the `link` tag so that it only loads when it is being printed.